# What does the `input` argument do in the system() function in R?

Tags: r

What does the `input` argument do in the system() function in R? For example in the code below

```
authentication_test <- "authentication_test aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket/ > /dev/null"

system(authentication_test, input = "q")
```

I don't understand what purpose the letter `q` serves.

Looking at the help file, `input` is described as

```
input: if a character vector is supplied, this is copied 
one string per line to a temporary file, and the standard 
input of command is redirected to the file.
```

but I still have trouble understanding what exactly it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` creates a temporary file which is used as STDIN for the `system` shell command.

Take for example the `cat` command:

```r
system("cat", input = "Line1\nLine2")
#Line1
#Line2
```

In your bash shell this would be the same as

```sh
echo -e "File1\nFile2" > file
cat < file
#Line1
#Line2
```